# 3 combo boxes all connected to 1 datasource, Need to be able to pick seperate options

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I have 3 combo boxes on a form that all connect to the same datasource. The datasource has 8 options that can be selected. How can I get to choose 3 different options in the combo boxes. As soon as I select 1 item all the combo boxes change to the same option.

```
Private Sub FrmExtras_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'RatesDataSet.Extras' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ExtrasTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PricingDataSet.Extras)
    End Sub
Private Sub CboOptions1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles CboOptions1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Trim(CboOptions1.Text) <> "O Pick Your Option" Then
            TxtQty1.Text = 1
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: @Could you please, explain more with code ? **It's hard to imagine your scenario**

Comment: Hi yeah its a form that has 3 combo boxes and a price calculation button. When the for loads it loads all the options in the comboboxes. I want to be able to select in combobox1 1 option, then in combobox 2 a different option, then if needed I would select a 3rd option in combobox3. The database is just 2 columns 1st being the options and the second is the price. so after the options are selected it would add in the prices as per selection and display it in a label. Hope that helps.

Comment: - What are those Options? - How do you populate your ComboBox? - What is your Database? .... Also, I suggest you add all those Info into your question.

Comment: Some examples of options are, Marker, Reduction, Paint, Cover, for examples. The comboboxes are populated in their properties under DataSource. I choose the ExtrasBindingSource. I did this for all 3 comboboxes. The Data base is called Rates.mdf

Comment: OK, you need to build Sql Query that does what you want, then execute the Query when you choose an Item from your ComboBox, then display result in the other two ComboBoxes accordingly.

Comment: When I select 1 option in the combo box all 3 boxes change to that selection, and if I change combobox 2 they all change to that option

Comment: `ComboBox1.DataSource = yourDataTable ComboBox2.DataSource = yourDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable() ...`. Bind TextBoxes to the Price column. Use the Binding object's [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format) and [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse) events for the conversions, if you need to bind to a another DataTable directly.

Comment: I would put this in the form load right?

Comment: Right after you have your DataTable available, in the same place where your binding your ComboBoxes now. If you pass the SelectedValue to TextBoxes, the TextBoxes need to be bound to another DataTable, where you store the selections made.

Comment: When I put it in the .defaultview isn't an option so it gives me an error. CboOptions1.DataSource = PricingDataSet
CboOptions2.DataSource = PricingDataSet.DefaultView.ToTable()

Comment: You're using a DataSet. You need to use the DataTable where these prices and descriptions are stored. You don't need a BindingSource for this, but you can use it nonetheless.

Comment: I don't have the binding coded its in the properties of the CboOptions.

Comment: You add bindings to the Controls that receive the value selected using the ComboBoxes, to bind those controls to another DataTable, where the selected values are stored. I assume you have a DataAdapter connected to this DataTable (to store the data to the database). Unless you use and INSERT/UPDATE query directly, but it's all the same.

Comment: Yes I have a ExtrasTableAdapter. but that doesn't have a defaultview either.

Comment: Simple - you should use different instances of data(DataTable, Collection or anything else) for every combobox

Comment: DefaultView belongs to a **DataTable**, not a DataAdapter. MSDN is online, you can get some good information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you only have one `CurrencyManager`. Three controls bound to the same data source with a single `CurrencyManager` will remain in sync.

The `BindingSource` component was introduced to provide a one-stop-shop for all things related to binding, including access to a `CurrencyManager`. Many off the members of a `BindingSource` pass through to the underlying `CurrencyManager`.

In this case, you need to create a separate `BindingSource` for each `ComboBox`, which will result in a separate `CurrencyManager`, which will result in independent selections. I see no binding code so I assume that you did your binding in the designer. Check the `DataSource` property of those `ComboBoxes` and I think you'll find that they are all bound to the same `BindingSource`. Check the `DataSource` and `DataMember` of that `BindingSource` and you should find that it is bound to that `DataTable` of your `DataSet`.

You need to add two new `BindingSources` to your form and bind them to the same `DataTable` in the same way. You can then bind those two `BindingSources` to two of the `ComboBoxes`. You should then find that you can make independent selections in all three.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the new `BindingContext` to other comboboxes.

```
combobox1.DataSource = results
combobox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue"
combobox1.ValueMember = "Value"

combobox2.BindingContext = New BindingContext()
combobox2.DataSource = results
combobox2.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue"
combobox2.ValueMember = "Value"
```